# Let $x$ be a real number. Let $d(x,0)$ denote the distance between $x$ and the origin. Let $f(x)=d(x,0)$.

Tags: functions

Let $x$ be a real number. Let $d(x,0)$ denote the distance between $x$ and the origin. Let $f(x)=d(x,0)$. Draw a graph of $f$ in the Cartersian plane. Is $f$ a function?

$f(x)=d(x,0)$ is this the same as $f(x)=|x|$? So yes it is a function?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between two real numbers $x,y$ is defined by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. So yes, $f(x)=|x|$ and $f$ is a function : absolute value, with well-known graph.